# Code for printing prime numbers from 1 to 65 is printing all prime numbers except 3 using Java.Why is it like that?

Tags: java, primes

I'm working on a Java program that prints all the prime numbers from 1 to 65. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       for (int i = 3; i < 65; i++) {
           for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j++) {
               if (i % j != 0) {
                   System.out.println(i);
               }
           }
        }
    }    
}
```

The code provided above prints all prime numbers except 3.

If I use the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 3;
        boolean isPrime = true;

        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;  // Exit the loop once a divisor is found
            }
        }

        if (isPrime) {
            System.out.println(number + " is a prime number.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(number + " is not a prime number.");
        }
    }
}
```

It is giving 3 as prime.  Why is the first code not printing 3?

Comment: Use debugger to step thru. print inbetween values. See the [faq] of this site

Comment: When `i = 3` and `j = 2`, then `j > sqrt(i)i`. Therefore, the loop is never entered. --- As an aside: the algorithm is not correct. It, for example, prints `10`, which is not prime.

Comment: "the logic is the same" ??? No, definitively not! Second is `break`ing out the loop as soon as a divisor is found - first is printing the number for each dividend that is not a divisor (Example `9` cannot be divided by `2`, so it is printed by first or, as mentioned in previous comment, `10` is not divisible by `3`)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, pay attention to where `j` evaluates to iterate starting from 2 to `Math.sqrt(i)`. When `i=3`, `Math.sqrt(i) = Math.sqrt(3) = 1.732`. Because `1.732<2`, the inside loop **does not get executed**.

As a result:

```java
if(i%j!=0){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

does not get executed.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Code for printing prime numbers from 1 to 65 is printing all prime numbers except 3 using Java.Why is it like that? ..."*

The first code will only print a prime number if it matches the *loop* conditions.

And, the second code prints the prime number *after* the *for-loop*.
Since *isPrime* is never set to *false*, *3* will be considered prime.

Answer (score 0):

> The code provided above prints all prime numbers except 3.

No it doesn't.  It prints the following which doesn't include `2` or `3` and prints composite numbers as well.

```
5 7 9 10 11 11 13 13 14 15 16 17 17 17 18 19 19 19 20 21 21 22 22 23 23
23 25 25 25 26 26 26 27 27 27 28 28 29 29 29 29 30 31 31 31 31 32 32 33
33 33 34 34 34 35 35 35 36 37 37 37 37 37 38 38 38 38 39 39 39 39 40 40
41 41 41 41 41 42 42 43 43 43 43 43 44 44 44 45 45 45 46 46 46 46 47 47
47 47 47 48 49 49 49 49 49 50 50 50 50 51 51 51 51 51 52 52 52 52 53 53
53 53 53 53 54 54 54 55 55 55 55 55 56 56 56 57 57 57 57 57 58 58 58 58
58 59 59 59 59 59 59 60 61 61 61 61 61 61 62 62 62 62 62 63 63 63 63 64
64 64 64
```

Here is what you need to do.

- first, just print `2` to avoid having to specially handle the only even prime.
  Otherwise, increment your loop values by `x += x == 2 ? 1 : 2` to bump by `1` if equal to `2` and by `2` there after.
- put an `outer` label before the outer loop
- iterate over the candidates starting with `3` and incrementing by `2`;
- iterate over the divisors the same way.  Use `Math.sqrt(i)+1` to avoid exiting the loop prematurely by checking for border cases.
- if a remainder is found, continue to the outer loop.
- move your print statement after the inner loop since none of the candidates were composite. If the inner loop finishes normally then what is left is a prime.

```
System.out.print(2);
outer:
for (int i = 3; i <= 65; i+=2) {
   for (int j = 3; j <= Math.sqrt(i)+1; j += 2) {
      if (i % j == 0) {
          continue outer; // not a prime
      }
   }
   System.out.print(" " +i);
}
```

prints

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61
```

Answer (score -1):

Lusine Baghdasaryan's answer is right.

Math.sqrt(3) = 1.7320508075688772

Math.sqrt() returns double data type so when compared with 2, Java converts it to below comparison:

2.0 < 1.7320508075688772.

The second sinppet of code predefined isPrime is true. That's why you got the result.

Also, your prime numbers result is incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isPrime=true;
        for (int i = 2; i < 65; i++) {
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                }
            }
            if(isPrime){
                System.out.println(i);
            }else{
                isPrime =true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Code-only answers are discouraged, as people should be able to learn from answers, instead of just copying & pasting code from the web. See [answer]. Can you [edit] your answer and add some explanation on how your code works?

Comment: Also, code only answers rarely are suitable to answer **why** questions.